# Extracting raw html from locally saved html file using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, extract

Relativally new to BeautifulSoup. Attempting to obtain raw html from locally saved html file. I've looked around and have found that I should probably be using Beautiful Soup for this. Though when I do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = r"C:\example.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")
text = soup.get_text()
print (text)
```

An empty string is printed out. I assume I'm missing some step. Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to `BeautifulSoup` is an actual HTML string, not a URL. Open the file, read its contents, and pass that in.

Answer (score 2):

Touching upon the previous answer, there are two ways to open an HTML file:

1.

```
with open("example.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp)
```

2.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("example.html"))
```